# Silverlight master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, master-pages

I am new to Silverlight and have decided to give it a go. I have no idea how to create a master page (page.xaml) using Silverlight...

Any help will be appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find my TemplatePanel implementation interesting for the master page scenario... (just place a TemplatePanel as the root element in your page, and define the template of the TemplatePanel in resources so it can be defined once)

http://www.nikhilk.net/Silverlight-TemplatePanel.aspx

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

As of SL 2.0, there is no "MasterPage" control in Silverlight. However, you could reproduce the effect by doing some simple content swapping with a ContentControl.

The simplest implementation would start by creating a UserControl that has your master content, then use a ContentControl to act as the content place holder (i.e. similar to ASP.NET). Then you can set the Content to be other UserControls.

In Silverlight 3.0, you can embed "Frame" controls to do the same thing.